# Running through def main function after a variable reaches len(ADCDATA) == 100000

Tags: python, keyboardinterrupt

The code only stops when a keyboardinterrupt is used.

A break was used though I took it out and the adc data was read and then the spi.close was skipped along with the update_sheet("PCEM SHT.1", ADCDATA)

I've tried using a different exception, raise exception based on the number of variables in ADCDATA, but with no effect

```
# import many libraries
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function  
from googleapiclient.discovery import build  
from httplib2 import Http  
from oauth2client import file, client, tools  
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials  
import datetime
import spidev # import the SPI driver


def read_mcp3002(channel):

### Working ADC Code

    return adc_data


def update_sheet(sheetname, my_list):  

###Working Update google sheet code
try:
    while True:
        Result=1##3.23#for 3302 [mV]..... Voltage=(High Voltage-Low Voltage)/(2^(# of conversion bits))
        voltage1=(read_mcp3002(0))
        voltage1k=voltage1*Result
        voltage2=(read_mcp3002(1))
        voltage2k=voltage2*Result  # This one #


        ADCDATA += [[voltage1k, voltage2k]]

        if len(ADCDATA) == 100000:
            #print(ADCDATA)
            ADCDATA = []
            print("+10000")


except KeyboardInterrupt: # Ctrl-C
    spi.close()


def main():  


    update_sheet("PCEM SHT.1", ADCDATA)


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

The desired result would be to automatically stop  at len(ADCDATA)=100000: if len(ADCDATA)==100000, it would run the code in the If statement, and also execute spi.close() and lastly run through def main()'s update_sheet("PCEM SHT1", ADCDATA).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deal with my problem by importing sys and placing a system exit(1) at the bottom of the & inside the if len(ADCDATA)==100000

```
if len(ADCDATA)==100000
```

print("PCEM DATA")
   spi.close()
   update_sheet"........")
   sys.exit(1)